# Should I protect a freshly sanded, untreated deck from the weather?

Tags: deck, staining, sanding, rain

I just Sanded my Deck. Unfortunately weather forecast has changed and it looks like it's going to rain for a week, so I don't have time to weather-proof it.

Should I cover my freshly-sanded deck with Tarp to prevent it from getting wet in the meantime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Water will raise the grain of your nice, smooth decking, requiring a re-sand. Also, rain will soak into the wood, requiring a significant dry-time delay before sealing.

Yes, you should tarp it.